# Mentioning location of paper submission while under review

Tags: ethics, united-states, etiquette

I just submitted my first paper to a rather prestigious conference/journal (“XYZ”) as an undergrad. I’m currently applying to jobs, so I’d like to mention “the paper is under review for XYZ”. However, a friend told me that it’s considered bad form to mention where one submitted a paper while it’s under review as someone can break the “blindness” of the review. This doesn’t seem right because if they want, they can just look up the title and my name is on the arxiv copy of the paper. Is he correct?

Comment: Unless the review is double blind, the reviewers already know the authors. Even in double blind reviewing, giving the paper's title & authors can break the blind.

Comment: It can be considered "bad form" because it can be pretentious. I've submitted the following three papers to _Nature_.

Comment: @Buffy My favorite is the news article written about the next new miracle cure, the definite proof of some long-suffering problem in mathematics, the standard medical care that's actually killing everyone off...all based on *real important science* that's been *submitted* for peer review! What higher recognition could such work ever hope to achieve?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't mention it; it doesn't mean anything.

You could have 30 papers under review in Science or Nature tomorrow (or substitute any favorite journal or conference in your field) if you wanted to spend a bunch of time with their manuscript submission software, and depending on venue a bunch of money on submission fees. What does that say about the quality of any of those submissions? Nothing.

I think that's a better reason to just leave such things as vaguely "submitted" or "in review"; it gives someone reading your CV information about the state of projects you've worked on, without attempting to make unearned claims about the prestige or value of the work.

Comment: Yes, just "submitted"  is a small token of your seriousness, without being toooo pretentious or presumptive.